# How do you write a macro to filter columns in an entire workbook by multiple values?

Tags: vba, excel

Hello All I have a question and I've thought out the logic just not sure about how to write the MACRO to it.

I pull data at work and we are only concerned about filtering sheets for certain items. All of the items are ALWAYS located in the same column K the column is titled Activity status and the first value always starts on Row 15.

What we need for example is to filter for **Not Started, Started, & In Process**
The problem is there are about 50 sheets to do this for. I know there's a simpler way by developing a macro.

```
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
For Each wSheet IN Worksheets
wSheet.ColumnK.Row15.Filter(Not Started, Started, In Process);
Next wSheet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more than two values to filter on with an [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx) you will have to pass in an array.

```
dim w as long, v as variant

v = array("Not Started", "Started", "In Process")

for w=1 to worksheets.count
    with worksheets(w)
        if .autofiltermode then .autofiltermode = false
        with .range(.cells(14, "K"), .cells(rows.count, "K").end(xlup))
            .autofilter field:=1, criteria1:=(v), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        end with
    end with
next w
```

Note that the `(v)` is in brackets. If you build your array first as a var then you need to wrap it in brackets when used as `criteria1:=(v)` in order that it is properly determined to be an array.

Comment: This is AMAZING !!!! how would I make it start at the filter at Row 14 on every sheet rather than 1 though ??  I tried changing " with .columns("K14")" and it threw me an error and also tried adding another "with .rows("14") underneath the with .columns("K") and that also gave me an error.

Comment: K14 has a header label. The only thing is there is data between row 1 and 14 that is needed so filtering from Row 14 would be way more beneficial. K14's header is Activity Status and in between that in row A and B there are data from Rows 2-13 that is needed so as long as that is displayed this is pin point what I need ! Row 1 also has a header though. Only in Column A.

Comment: K14 is the Activity Status cell. The filter gets created on K1 though.

Comment: See revision above to start the filter at row 14.